# Gstreamer not writing headers of mp4 file on EOS when audio is unlinked from mp4mux

Tags: c++, c, audio, gstreamer

So I am working in an old version of gstreamer for legacy reasons (1.40). We use it heavily throughout the code base. Thus forcing me not to change. I am trying to cutoff an audio source from a pipeline by simply disconnecting it however even though I send EOS through the pipeline from the appsrc's the mp4 header is not written when the audio is disconnected, but they are written when it is connected.

Does anybody know what is up. One thing I have tried is totally removing the entire audio pipeline from the bin using gst_bin_remove_many but the mp4 headers are still not written on EOS?

I have psuedo code for the complexm pipeline below

```cpp
//INIT FUNC...
    GstElementFactory *appsrcfactory = gst_element_factory_find ( "appsrc" );
    GstElement *appSrc = gst_element_factory_create ( appsrcfactory, "Video App Src" ); //stored in a global manager
    GstElement *appAudioSrc = gst_element_factory_create ( appsrcfactory, "Audio App Src" );//stored in a global manager
    //other elements created here ...
    GstElementFactory *muxfactory = gst_element_factory_find ( "mp4mux" );
    GstElement *mux = gst_element_factory_create ( pFactory, "mux" ); //stored in a global manager
    GstPad  *videopad = gst_element_get_request_pad( mux, "video_%u" ); //stored in a global manager
    GstPad  *audiopad = gst_element_get_request_pad( mux, "audio_%u" ); //stored in a global manager

    //pipeline bin add and linking and probe setup done here

    GstPad *audioOutPad = gst_element_get_static_pad ( audioOutputElement, "src" );
    GstPad *videoOutPad = gst_element_get_static_pad ( videoOutputElement, "src" );
    if ( gst_pad_link ( videoOutPad, videopad ) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK ||
            gst_pad_link ( audioOutPad, audiopad ) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK ) 
    {
        gst_object_unref ( bus );
        gst_object_unref ( pipeline );
        pipeline = nullptr;
        bus = nullptr;
        return;
    }
    gst_object_unref ( audioOutPad );
    gst_object_unref ( videoOutPad );

//START RECORDING FUNC...

    if( AudioPresent && audiopad == nullptr )
    {
        audiopad = gst_element_get_request_pad( mux, "audio_%u" );
        GstPad *audioOutPad = gst_element_get_static_pad ( audioOutputElement, "src" );
        if ( gst_pad_link ( audioOutPad, audiopad ) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK ) 
        {
            gst_object_unref ( bus );
            gst_object_unref ( pipeline );
            pipeline = nullptr;
            bus = nullptr;
            return;
        }
        gst_object_unref ( audioOutPad );
    }
    else if( !AudioPresent && audiopad != nullptr)
    {
        GstPad *audioOutPad = gst_pad_get_peer( audiopad );

        if ( gst_pad_unlink ( audioOutPad, audiopad ) != TRUE )
        {
            gst_object_unref ( bus );
            gst_object_unref ( pipeline );
            pipeline = nullptr;
            bus = nullptr;
            return;
        }
        gst_object_unref ( audioOutPad );
        gst_element_release_request_pad ( mux, audiopad );
        gst_object_unref ( audiopad );
        audiopad = nullptr;
    }
    gst_element_set_state ( m_pGSTRecorder, GST_STATE_PLAYING );

//Data ss pushed to the appsrc's from our render pipeline

//STOP RECORDING FUNC...
    gst_app_src_end_of_stream ( GST_APP_SRC ( appSrc ) );
    if ( AudioPresent )
    {
        gst_app_src_end_of_stream ( GST_APP_SRC( appAudioSrc ) );
    }
    gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered( bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_MESSAGE_EOS);\
    gst_element_set_state ( m_pGSTRecorder, GST_STATE_NULL );
```